# Scrapy identify redirect and stop for loop

Tags: python, function, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to iterate over some pages. The different pages of are marked with or10,or20,or30 etc. for the website. i.e.

```
/Restaurant_Review
```

is the first page

```
/Restaurant_Review-or10
```

Is the second page

```
/Restaurant_Review-or20
```

3rd page etc.

The problem is that I get redirected from those sites to the normal url (1st one) if the -or- version doesnt exist. I'm currently looping over a range in a for loop, and dynamically changing the -or- value.

```
 def parse(self,response):
     l = range(100)
     reviewRange = l[10::10]

     for x in reviewRange:
          yield((url+"-or"+str(x)), callback=self.parse_page)

def parse_page(self,response):
    #do something
    #How can I from here tell the for loop to stop
    if(oldurl == response.url):
         return break
     #this doesnt work
```

The problem is that I need to do the request even if the page doesn't exist, and this is not scalable. I've tried comparing the URLs, but still did not understand how I can return from the parse_page() function something that would tell the parse() function to stop.

Comment: Is there nothing on the page itself that indicates more pages exist? For example a "Next" button? Can you post a full URL here?

Comment: the page is Tripadvisor. The pages are loaded with JS so I can't access them with scrapy alone.

Comment: I know this wasn't your question, but those `-orXX-` URL's do seem to contain page number links. Check in scrapy shell to get the links: `response.css('.pageNum::attr(href)').getall()`

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed solve my problem. May I ask what were the steps taken to find this selector? I couldnt find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what is in `response.meta.get('redirect_urls')`, for example. In case you have something there, retry original url with `dont_filter`. 
Or try to catch such cases with  [RetryMiddleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry).

Comment: So I create a condition that checks in (parse()) that if the url that I'm about to yield is in the "response.meta.get('redirect_urls')" list? and if so then I can break.

Comment: In this variable you have list of redirect urls, so, take original url from there or pass it in meta earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the actual question, but rather an alternative solution that does not require redirect detection.

In the HTML you can already find all those pagination URLs by using:

```
response.css('.pageNum::attr(href)').getall()
```

---

Regarding @Anton's question in a comment about how I got this:

You can check this by opening a random restaurant review page with the Scrapy shell:

`scrapy shell "https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/Restaurant_Review-g32655-d348825-Reviews-Brent_s_Delicatessen_Restaurant-Los_Angeles_California.html"`

Inside the shell you can view the received HTML in your browser with:

`view(response)`

There you'll see that it includes the HTML (and that specific class) for the pagination links. The real website does use Javascript to render the next page, but it does so by retrieving the *full* HTML for the next page based on the URL. Basicallty, it just replaces the entire page, there's very little additional processing involved. So this means if you open the link yourself you get the full HTML too. Hence, the Javascript issue is irrelevant here.